# cmake extract substring from variable

Tags: cmake

I have variable CC_OPTIONS has value set like below

`-arch arm64 -mcpu=abc1 -c --debug -O2 -static -fstack-protector -ffreestanding -nostartfiles -std=c11`

I wanted to extract `-mcpu=abc1` from CC_OPTIONS

Tried below approach, but getting more than what i wanted.

`string(REGEX REPLACE ".*mcpu=(.*)\ .*" "\\1" CPU_TYPE "${CC_OPTIONS}")`

any suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand - do you want to extract a *fixed* string `-mcpu=abc1` or the `=abc1` part which might vary?

Comment: thanks for reply, anything is fine from those 2, either the value abc1, or whole part -mcpu=abc1 to CPU_TYPE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like that:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.11)
project (HELLO)
set(CC_OPTIONS "-arch arm64 -mcpu=abc1 -c --debug -O2 -static -fstack-protector -ffreestanding -nostartfiles -std=c11")
message(${CC_OPTIONS})

string(REGEX MATCH "\\-mcpu=[^ $]+" CPU_TYPE ${CC_OPTIONS})
message(${CPU_TYPE})
```

Example:

```
$ cmake .
-arch arm64 -mcpu=abc1 -c --debug -O2 -static -fstack-protector -ffreestanding -nostartfiles -std=c11
-mcpu=abc1
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/ja/cmake
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use [`if(MATCHES)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html) you can get character groups of the match using [`CMAKE_MATCH_<n>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MATCH_n.html#variable:CMAKE_MATCH_%3Cn%3E)

```
set(MY_VAR "-arch arm64 -mcpu=abc1 -c --debug -O2 -static -fstack-protector -ffreestanding -nostartfiles -std=c11")

if (MY_VAR MATCHES "^([^ ]+ +)*(-mcpu=[^ ]+)( +[^ ]+)*$")
    message(STATUS "Found match: ${CMAKE_MATCH_2}")
else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "mismatch")
endif()
```